# Responsive email table keeps breaking - what is causing this?

Tags: html, css, html-email

I'm working on an HTML Email which is working perfectly in the multiple email client/browser combinations I need to support save for this one problem which I just cannot figure out. I have a table that is `600px` (which is the width of the email) wide and within this there is another table which is comprised of a top and bottom 'curve' image which has some text in the middle. As this email is responsive, when the browser window is made smaller the inner grey table just 'breaks'. I know this because I am using Litmus to test across a multitude of browser/email clients combinations.

Note: this ONLY happens when email is "resized" i.e. only on mobile email clients. If you look at the below fiddle, the portion I am talking about is the inner grey box that begins `The Victims of Fraud...`. This box (when resized) just will not play nice. I have tried everything I can think of, using padding, removing padding, nested tables and everything inbetween. It's driving me crazy.

In order to see what I mean open the fiddle then make the `HTML` window smaller.

Here is a fiddle to try and illustrate what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/39gzj/2/

UPDATE: If you look using Firebug / Chrome Developer Settings, you will see that for some reason the table has this magic `2px` added to the inner grey table. This is what I need to eradicate!

UPDATE 2: Tried again with what was posted in the comments but again this does not work.

http://jsfiddle.net/39gzj/2/

UPDATE 3 - I've even tried using a media query to explicitly resize this middle box but it still doesn't work. Here is the updated fiddle; http://jsfiddle.net/39gzj/5/

Comment: Give your table `cell-spacing: 0;` or `border-spacing: 0;` can't remember which off the top of my head.

Comment: @gaynorvader The second one.

Comment: @MiniRagnarok I had a feeling `cell-spacing` was the old html property all right. Cheers!

Comment: I've added this to the fiddle but this doesn't work

Comment: @gaynorvader also, you can see from the fiddle that the table already has `cellspacing` of `0` multiple times.

Comment: @Kiz Then you're problem isn't the magic 2px being added to the table. I've tried to replicate your issue but I don't know what you mean by "breaks".

Comment: Look at the fiddle. Re-size the `HTML` window. You will see that the inner grey box doesn't line up properly. @MiniRagnarok

Comment: @Kiz Set the table's border-spacing manually to 2px and you'll see why that's not your problem.

Comment: @Kiz It looks like you're having a conflict since the top and bottom rows are images and the middle row is a background color. The browser re-sizes images and the background slightly differently. My guess is that the images are trying to keep their dimensions when you resize.

Comment: @MiniRagnarok yes exactly. This is what I need to correct :(

Comment: Using separate 24x24 corner images apposed to a full width one would be an easy workaround.

Comment: @John I've tried this. But this doesn't work either. See updated fiddle.

Comment: If I resize the jsFiddle iframe **exactly** to 346px width, the image corner fits in right place... and if continue resizing, the layout breaks again (?). Maybe this issue comes for the [Sub Pixel problem](http://ejohn.org/blog/sub-pixel-problems-in-css/)? Just speculating...

Comment: Media queries and *not* the way to format for emails. You need to code like you're living in 1990: none of the problem clients work with modern standards. Even gmail only supports **inline** CSS.

Comment: @MikeMarcacci I know they're not, but support for them is getting better (incredibly slowly). The media queries work for iOS devices and a few others but for everything else, `%'s` and `max-widths` are what we use to achieve the responsive aspect which in all previous campaigns has been fine. This was built from scratch with a few slight changes hence the inevitable issues!

Comment: Kiz, I'm having trouble getting it to break.  There are some convex edges on the left and right that seem to change a bit when resizing, but they took me some time to notice.  Is this the problem you are having?  If not, might you be able to throw up a screenshot of the broken layout?

Comment: @OscillatingEthmoid, If you resize the small HTML window in the last fiddle, you can see that middle row that the `Victims of Fraud` wording expands to be slightly larger than the 2 "top-curve" and "bottom-curve" images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, so I finally managed to fix this but needed to use the media queries to fix the "breaking" of that middle row. Here's what I did;

Use a media query to explicitly size EVERY SINGLE ROW! So now, the image resizes properly, but once it gets to mobile viewport size it just snaps down to the correct size (max 300px) which you can see in the CSS. Here is the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/39gzj/6/)

Here is the media query that worked:

```
@media only screen and (min-width:300px) and (max-width: 500px) { /* MOBILE CODE */
    *[id=mobile] {
        width:300px!important;
    }
}
```

This I know isn't really the correct way to answer this as I still haven't fixed the initial problem (why the table is breaking) so no sure what the mods wish to do with this bounty I put out there.

EDIT: As pointed out helpfully in the comments, if the screen size is BELOW `300px`the email will automatically become normal size again, this can again be fixed by changing the media query but as noted, this answer currently solves issues specifically for the email clients/browser combinations I need to support.

Comment: In email marketing I found that @media isnt recognized by gmail or yahoo. Am i wrong??

Comment: Indeed you are correct, see here: http://www.emailonacid.com/blog/details/C13/media_queries_in_html_emails. You might also want to check out this http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Comment: Im not sure but maybe overflow might be the solution, trying to figure out if it can fix it. Btw thats a great site, i use it when im having the same problems, we generate emails that inform customers of there product shipping information. We just came across what you were dealing with, and the problems your having is with mobile email which we never typically test but it seems it may be necessary to test now.

Comment: I have tried `overflow:hidden` but this hasn't worked! If you can get a variation of this working then that would be excellent.

Comment: @Kiz Media queries isn't a good solution. They are not supported in web clients as mentioned by Cam above. Media queries should only be used where there is a solid fallback. Did you try my second solution with the border-radius and padding?

Comment: @John yes I did and it didn't work. It may not be the solution but it works in all the client/browser combinations we need to support (30+). This includes it scaling correctly for mobile devices including (but not limited to); Android, Android Gmail, Android Yahoo and iPhone.

Comment: I'd also like to note that in this particular example, if your screen shrinks *below* `300px`, you snap right back to the large-mode.

Comment: @TroyAlford yes you are correct. I should add that to this. However, as I mentioned, it works for what we need to support and thankfully older versions of Blackberry OS and screens with a smaller than 300px resolution don't need to be supported. I could of course fix this by changing the media query too.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting up your table like this instead:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#cccccc" style="border-radius: 5px; padding:30px;">
  <tr>
    <td>
text here. Put this inside a container with any media queries, should always stretch to full width.
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer dude. I've tried this to no avail! This is driving me insane. No matter what I do this box just will not resize properly. I've even tried explicitly defining the width using a media query!!

Comment: @Kiz Sorry - I forgot you were looking for something resizable. I updated the code. I'm using border radius instead of images. It's not 100% supported, but resizes within any element. If you want to use images, you'd have to set the media query to adjust the width of the center td's in the previous fixed example I posted.

Comment: Try taking all of your widths off of the style area and put them as a property, then make your text area smaller so your row would be 560px but your table data would be 400px, with padding to fill in the rest, that may work. But make sure your width and height are properties not style, if doing inline coding.

Comment: @John, he needs to move some of his code out of style, that may be one of his problems.

Answer (score 1):

If you pull your static-width columns out that you're using for spacing and apply margin to the sub-tables to accomplish your spacing everything should line up properly.  I'd imagine the spacing columns are the source of your angst.

Comment: You're not wrong there! I think it's that too, from debugging with Firefox and Chrome, I can see that for some reason these spacers seem to have a mind of their own.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using min-width. To limit the size that it will shrink to. I would assume that if it shrinks it should only shrink to the point before it breaks. Am I right?

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a try and let you know how I get on.

Comment: support for `min-width` is not good so I haven't used it. Also, it doesn't seem to fix the issue anyway.

Comment: @Cam Min-width isn't supported by Outlook